# how to Disappear app icon from launcher?

Tags: android

I want to disappear my app icon from launcher and app will automatically restart after some time.
I did code for hiding icon below:

```
 try {
       PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.package.name", "com.class.name");
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR@@", "" + e.toString());
    }
```

this is code for reopening my app after some time

```
public void initializingTimerTask() {
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mIsInForegroundMode == false) {
                        Intent LaunchIntent=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
                        LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

**The error:**

```
 11-16 14:10:02.802 18503-18503/com.package.newproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
    main Process: com.package.newproject, PID: 18503 java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.mspatel.package.newproject.AutoOpenAppService$1$1.run(AutoOpenAppService.java:101) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

but when turn to restart application app going to crash please help me.

Comment: Could you please make it little more clear..

Comment: post log here for help

Comment: if you don't define Launcher property in AndroidManifest, it won't get launched.

Comment: i have app that will reopen after every 30 second , i make service for it. also i want to hide it app icon from launche , i shown these code ago , icon is successfully hide but when app is reopen after 30 second , app going to crash .. please help any other info. you want i can give u

Comment: Can you add crash report here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly than here it is.
To hide the icon use this:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.sstudio.sysUtil.TheActivity.class); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

And remember, before opening the app again, you need to unhide the icon first, and then open the app, or else it will crash. do it like this:

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, TheActivity.class);
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP); // to unhide the icon and to prevent the app from crashing
        Intent i = new Intent(context, TheActivity.class);// use your own intent as required
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);// and add flags as required
        context.startActivity(i);//and open activity
```

I had the same problem. This did solve mine. Hope it solves yours too.

**Edit**
change your code:

```
public void initializingTimerTask() {
timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mIsInForegroundMode == false) {
                    Intent LaunchIntent=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
                    LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
    }
};}
```

with this:

```
 public void initializingTimerTask() {
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mIsInForegroundMode == false) {
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), TheActivity.class);
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);        
                        Intent LaunchIntent=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
                        LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };}
```

Comment: thanks for reply,sumo but its not working for me, i have only one activity is there for reopen i have service class so, is there any changes

Comment: thank you so much, simo its working, but when android version up to marshmallow when app it install automatically closed , and once again thak you so much